# python panda dataframe wont print columns with same name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

```
import pandas as pd

burgerCalories = [300,250,380,474]
drinkCalories = [150,140,120,175]
sideCalories = [100,57,70,0]
dessertCalories = [167,266,75,0]

menuNames = ['burgers','drinks','sides','desserts']
burgerNames = ['cheese burger','ham burger','fish burger','veggie burger']
drinkNames = ['pepsi','orange juice','milk','orange juice']
sideNames = ['fries','baked potato','chef salad','no side order']
dessertNames = ['apple pie','sundae','fruit cup','no dessert']

df =pd.DataFrame({
    'burgers':burgerNames, 'calories':burgerCalories,
    'drinks':drinkNames, 'calories':drinkCalories,
    'sides':sideNames, 'calories':drinkCalories,
    'desserts':dessertNames, 'calories':drinkCalories})

print(df)
```

Pandas prints 'calories' and the column itself exactly once. however the 3 other columns also containing 'calories' dont print. interestingly df.shape returns that the shape of the dataframe is (4, 5) when it should be (4, 8).

the [pandas duplicate documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/duplicates.html) isnt any help. this is a known concern that the pandas team have tried to address with their own complex solutions

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. Part of the problem here is that a dictionary cannot have duplicate keys, so each time you write over the `calories` value before the dictionary is passed to `pd.DataFrame(...)`.

Comment: You simply need to construct the dictionary so you do not have duplicate keys. something as simple as 'burger_calories', 'drink_calories' etc would work.

Comment: You _could_ do something like: `df = pd.DataFrame(zip(*[burgerNames, burgerCalories, drinkNames, drinkCalories, sideNames, sideCalories, dessertNames, dessertCalories]), columns=['burgers', 'calories', 'drinks', 'calories', 'sides', 'calories', 'desserts', 'calories'])` but as the documentation points out, there are many issues with having duplicate column names.